# Alternative for 'ddl_lock_timeout' in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

In oracle 11g it's allowed to set session and system parameter, which's called [`ddl_lock_timeout`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams068.htm). It's very useful when you need to execute some statement and resources are highly used (in order to avoid [ORA-00054 exception](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00054.php)).

But the case is that there's no such a parameter in 10g.

Of course, I'm able to use such a cosntruction as:

```
DECLARE START_DATE DATE := SYSDATE;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    IF SYSDATE>START_DATE+30/60/60/24 THEN
      EXIT;
    END IF;
    BEGIN
      <some statement>
      EXIT;
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF sqlcode != -54 THEN
        RAISE;
      END IF;
    END;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

And by using it, I will try to execute the statement for 30 seconds in a cycle, but the thing here is that the statement is executed many many times and could cause some troubles (i'm not sure but I feel it somehow), but using `ddl_lock_timeout` the statement is executed only once and then waits for resources which is much fluffier.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Oracle recommendation is: "Do not use DDL for business logic".

Answer (score 2):

This is an explanation of why LOCK TABLE does not necessarily work.

```
LOCK TABLE - trick may not be working in all situations.

Session 1:                              Session 2:

create table table1(a number);
insert into table1 values(1);
commit;
update table1 set a = 2;



                                    lock table table1 in exclusive mode;
                                    <waits...>



commit;
                                        "Table(s) Locked." 

update table1 set a = 3;  <-- notice session 1 goes in queue now. 

                                        DDL fails with "resource busy with NOWAIT".
                                    Reason is DDL first commit the previous transaction 
                                    before executing the DDL.  And when it commits 
                                    session 1 gets the lock as it was already in queue.
```

Comment: Thanks.  You're right, my answer won't work, I'll delete it. I guess now the best answer is "there is no good alternative".